# Why is my normal navbar disappearing when I click on the menu icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the navbar to stay where it is without disappearing.
Here's my code:

```js
var sideBar = document.getElementById('sidebar')
var menuIcon = document.getElementById('menu-icon')

function show() {
  menuIcon.style.display = "none"
  sideBar.style.display = "Block"
}

function hide() {
  menuIcon.style.display = "inline"
  sideBar.style.display = "none"
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/*
Normal navbar on top of page
*/

body {
  height: 1000vh;
}

.normal {
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.normal .normal-menu .menu-icon i {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.normal .normal-menu .menu-icon i:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.normal .normal-menu .title {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*sidebar styles*/

.sidebar {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  display: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.sidebar .navbar .logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .navbar .close-icon {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .navbar .close-icon:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Aaqil Abdullah</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="normal" id="normal">
    <ul class="normal-menu" id="normal-menu">
      <span class="menu-icon" id="menu-icon" onclick="show()"><i class="bx bx-menu"></i
        ></span>
      <a href="index.html" class="title" id="title">Aaqil Abdullah</a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="logo"><a href="index.html">Aaqil Abdullah</a></span>
      <span class="close-icon" onclick="hide()"><i class="bx bx-x"></i></span>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>

  <div class="container">

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you have to do some debug.... For example... on click you hide sidebar.... _sideBar.style.display = "none"_

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because yourself are doing it, you need to remove these lines from your js

```
var menuIcon = document.getElementById('menu-icon');
menuIcon.style.display = "none";
menuIcon.style.display = "inline";
```

```js
const sideBar = document.getElementById("sidebar");

function show() {
  sideBar.style.display = "block";
}

function hide() {
  sideBar.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/*
Normal navbar on top of page
*/

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.normal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}

.normal .normal-menu .menu-icon i {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.normal .normal-menu .menu-icon i:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.normal .normal-menu .title {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*sidebar styles*/

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.sidebar .navbar .logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .navbar .close-icon {
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar .navbar .close-icon:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li:hover {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}

.sidebar .navbar .menu li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="normal" id="normal">
  <ul class="normal-menu" id="normal-menu">
    <span class="menu-icon" id="menu-icon" onclick="show()"><i class="bx bx-menu"></i></span>
    <a href="index.html" class="title" id="title">Aaqil Abdullah</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="logo"><a href="index.html">Aaqil Abdullah</a></span>
    <span class="close-icon" onclick="hide()"><i class="bx bx-x"></i></span>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Interests</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```